# Image /w border-radius, hidden overflow & overlay leaks

Tags: html, css

I have a image inside a container that has a border radius and overflow set to hidden. Inside the container there is also an element that is overlaid the image. The overlay does not cover up the clipped corner of the image. Here's my code, codepen, and a screenshot of what I'm referring to. How do you go about fixing this issue? I see it in all the desktop browsers.

[image]

```css
body {
  background: #333;
  padding: 50px;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 330px;
        object-fit: cover;
        object-position: center;
}

.overlay {
  padding: 20px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="overlay">Hello world!</div>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/HPL2GGA.jpg" />
</div>
```

**https://codepen.io/starkana/pen/oNgNNKV**

Comment: does it have anything to do with your alpha value?